# Character counter supposed to cut text off but does not when it is copied in

Tags: javascript

I have a character counter that cuts off the text and doesn't allow the user to keep typing once the maximum limit has been reached.  This works when the text is being entered but for some reason when text that is greater than the max is copied in it only cuts off some of the text and this means that the the count is still greater than the max.  It also displays 0 characters remaining when it is copied in but when i count the characters it is still greter than the max.

```
function textCounter(field,field2,maxlimit)
{
  var countfield = document.getElementById(field2);
 if ( field.value.replace(/\n/g, "\n\r").length > maxlimit ) {
   field.value = field.value.replace(/\n/g, "\n\r").substring( 0,maxlimit).replace(/\n\r/g, "\n");
 } else {
  countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.replace(/\n/g, "\n\r").length;
 }
 }
```

Above is the javascript function.  Any help so that when text is copied in that is greater than the max it cuts the text off at the correct part so the form can be submitted.

Comment: What's wrong with the `maxlength` attribute?

Comment: I have the max length set but when it is copied in it is allowing more characters than the max length states.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, I'd take a look at the maxlength attribute.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp

Specifically speaking, I guess your code is not being executed "on paste", only on keypress. On which event do you fire the textCounter? Can you provide the code of the text area?

Comment: '<textarea maxlength="${TEXT_AREA_LENGTH}" name="${status.expression}" onkeyup="textCounter(this,'${status.expression}.counter',${TEXT_AREA_LENGTH});">${status.value}</textarea>'

Comment: okay. my solution would be to add a timer beneath the textarea, in your case it would read
<script>setInterval(function(){textCounter(this,'${status.expression}',50);}, ${TEXT_AREA_LENGTH});</script>

As far as I can see, the problem you are having is that your browser ignores the maxlength (possibly IE) and pasting (clicking) does not fire the onkeyup-event. One possibility would have been to listen to all possible events (including onchange), in my opinion the timer is the simplest solution.